# How to filter exact matched value from ExtJS store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am filtering my extJS store.

`grid.store.filter(this.myFilterValue);`

My store is filtering. Now the problem is if `this.myFilterValue = "ATR"` then it suppose to filter value which having only "ATR" value. But in my case it is filtering all the value which have ATR character like `ATRX,ATRY,ATRZ`. How to overcome from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use store's [filterBy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore.html#method-filterBy) method .Giving sample below wrt your code:

```
grid.store.filterBy(function(record){
  //here i assumed record.filterValue as filterable property.You can take anything
  if(myFilterValue==record.filterValue)
     return true;
  else
     return false;
});
```

Check this and reply here.

Comment: My grid is filtering here by line `grid.store.filter(this.myFilterValue);` So do I need to write a separate function.

Comment: Also not able to pass `myFilterValue` inside the function.

Comment: you will have to declare & define that variable outside filter function then you can access it.

Comment: Thank you. But what if I need to filter with multiple myFilter value. I can write in for loop right.

Comment: yes , write those in loop and finally return true or false.

Comment: In loop this is working only for 1 `myFilterValue` not for all.

Comment: how you are writing it give some example.